# Optimized alternative to CGContextDrawImage

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm currently working a lot with CoreGraphics on OSX.

I've run Time Profiler over my code and found the biggest hang-up is in CGContextDrawImage. It's part of a loop that gets called many times per second.

I don't have any way of optimizing this code per se (since it's in the Apple libraries) - but I am wondering if there's a speedier alternative or way to improve the speed.

I'm using CGContextDraw image after some blend-mode code such as: `CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDifference);` so alternative implementations would need to be able to support blending.

**Time profiler results:**

```
3658.0ms   15.0%    0.0               CGContextDrawImage
3658.0ms   15.0%    0.0                ripc_DrawImage
3539.0ms   14.5%    0.0                 ripc_AcquireImage
3539.0ms   14.5%    0.0                  CGSImageDataLock
3539.0ms   14.5%    1.0                   img_data_lock
3465.0ms   14.2%    0.0                    img_interpolate_read
2308.0ms    9.4%    7.0                     resample_band
1932.0ms    7.9%    1932.0                   resample_byte_h_3cpp_vector
369.0ms     1.5%    369.0                    resample_byte_v_Ncpp_vector
1157.0ms    4.7%    2.0                     img_decode_read
1150.0ms    4.7%    8.0                      decode_data
863.0ms     3.5%    863.0                     decode_swap
267.0ms     1.0%    267.0                     decode_byte_8bpc_3
```

**Update:**

The actual source is something along the lines of the following:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (CGImageRef)createBlendedImage:(CGImageRef)image
                     secondImage:(CGImageRef)secondImage
                       blendMode:(CGBlendMode)blendMode
{
    // Get the image width and height
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    // Set the frame
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    // Create context with alpha channel
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                 width,
                                                 height,
                                                 CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image),
                                                 CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image),
                                                 CGImageGetColorSpace(image),
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    if (!context) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Draw the image inside the context
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, frame, image);

    // Set the blend mode and draw the second image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, blendMode);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, frame, secondImage);

    // Get the masked image from the context
    CGImageRef blendedImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return blendedImage;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (CGImageRef)createImageTick
{
    // `self.image` and `self.previousImage` are two instance properties (CGImageRefs)

    // Create blended image (stage one)
    CGImageRef stageOne = [self createBlendedImage:self.image
                                       secondImage:self.previousImage
                                         blendMode:kCGBlendModeXOR];

    // Create blended image (stage two) if stage one image is 50% red
    CGImageRef stageTwo = nil;

    if ([self isImageRed:stageOne]) {
        stageTwo = [self createBlendedImage:self.image
                                secondImage:stageOne
                                  blendMode:kCGBlendModeSourceAtop];
    }

    // Release intermediate image
    CGImageRelease(stageOne);

    return stageTwo;
}
```

Comment: It's nice that you actually profiled the code before trying to do premature optimization. If your code is running slow, though, I wouldn't blame it on the library - I believe you will need to re-design the code (reduce complexity by changing algorithm, or performing some other kind of "clever" improvement) in order to have it run significantly faster.

Comment: Looks like some time is being spent in decoding and byte swapping the image data. You should try and use iphone-optimized/crushed PNGs if possible.

Comment: A lot of time is being spent resampling the image. Is it possible to resize the image in advance, so that you don't have to do it when you draw? Are you drawing the same image several times at the same size, or are you drawing different images? Are you animating it?

Comment: @JeremyRoman et al: Thank you so much for your comments. I am drawing the same image a couple of times per loop, onto different contexts with different filters, and combining with new images. Does resampling include switching from RGB to RGBA? What could I try to speed up or eliminate resampling?

Comment: It would help to know more about what your code actually does at a high level. e.g. Are you drawing an animation? If so, have you looked into whether Core Animation would be more efficient for your use case?

Comment: Cheers @JeremyRoman - I've added some example code. It's not animating per se, but I am processing similar images over and over again many times per second. I'm currently managing the image processing using a GCD queue which effectively calls createImageTick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @JeremyRoman et al: Thank you so much for your comments. I am drawing the same image a couple of times per loop, onto different contexts with different filters, and combining with new images. Does resampling include switching from RGB to RGBA? What could I try to speed up or eliminate resampling? – Chris Nolet

This is what Core Image is for. See the [Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185) for details. `CGContext` is designed for rendering final images to the screen, which it sounds like is not your goal with every image you're creating.

Comment: I will actually be writing many of these images to disk (in fast succession, onto a virtual RAM drive). Better to move the image processing to Core Image, then use `createCGImage:fromRect:` coupled with `CGImageDestinationRef` to write, or does that warrant sticking with CG all the way through?

Comment: See WWDC 2013 session 509 (Core Image Effects and Techniques). Core Image is at its best when you can keep the data on the GPU as long as possible. Moving data to the GPU and back is expensive. So ideally you want to move data to the GPU, apply lots of filters, and then render it directly to the screen (faster) or back to CPU memory (slower). The real performance key is keeping the pipeline full, so you need to learn how data moves between the CPU and GPU. See also http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_performance/ci_performance.html

Comment: Also worth checking out https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage: faster than CIImage and easier (faster) transitions to and from CGImage.